# dynamically change the my label text with selection value of my comboBox?

Tags: javascript, combobox, label

I am using classic asp and want to dynamically change the my label text with selection value of my comboBox. If I select 1 on comboBox my label text= "hello" . if I select 2 than my label Text="how Are You"...

On page load my default label text = "Hello". and my comboBox and label inside the table.

```
function changeLabel(){

       if( document.getElementById('mycomboBoxID').value != 1 )
       {
        document.getElementById('LabelID').innerHTML = "how Are You"
       }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a question about JavaScript, not Classic ASP. To set the HTML content of LabelID with the **value** of your combobox (mycomboBoxID) you can do the following. I presume your changeLabel function is wired up to the onchange event of the combox.

```
function changeLabel(){
    document.getElementById('LabelID').innerHTML = document.getElementById('mycomboBoxID').value;
}
```

If instead of the value of the combo box you want the **text** of the selected item then you could do this instead:

```
function changeLabel(){
    document.getElementById('LabelID').innerHTML = document.getElementById('mycomboBoxID').options[document.getElementById('mycomboBoxID').selectedIndex].text;
}
```